# How can I enable click on a svg line in angular2

Tags: angular, svg, onclick, line

I have a line drawn through svg and I need to catch the click event on it. However when I set the onclick to a function, I get an error.

```
 <div id ="middle" class="col-lg-2 col-xs-3">  
      <svg width="300" height="2000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
             <line id="line2"   [attr.x1]= "from_x0"   
              [attr.y1]="from_y0"  [attr.x2]="to_x"  
              [attr.y2]="to_y" stroke-width="2" stroke="green" 
              onclick ="OnClick()"//>
     </svg>
</div>
```

The error I am getting is

Uncaught ReferenceError: OnClick is not defined
at SVGLineElement.onclick (:3000/#/app/tables/tablelist/tableedit/1:1)

My OnClick function is below

```
OnClick (){
  console.log('clicked on line')
}
```

Would appreciate any pointers to resolve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular event binding is `(event)="..."`

```
<line id="line2"   [attr.x1]= "from_x0" [attr.y1]="from_y0"   
 [attr.x2]="to_x" [attr.y2]="to_y" stroke-width="2" stroke="green"   
 (click)="OnClick()"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, i did try that first but must have made some silly mistake. It works fine  now.

Comment: No worries. Happens all the time :D. Glad to hear you could make it work.

Comment: This still isn't working for me, when clicking a path :-(